# constructor error , cannot find

Tags: java

it says cannot find Constructor Person() in class person, but i have class person. heres my code

```
public class Person{

    private String name;
    private int age;
    public String details;

    public Person(final String name, final int age){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

and the test person class

```
public class TestPerson{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int q;
        System.out.println(args.length + "objects created");
        for(q = 1; q < args.length; q++){
            final Person p1 = new Person();
            for(int x = 0; x < args[q].length(); x++){
                args[q].split(",");
                p1.setDetails(name, age);
                System.out.println(p1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As stated below, there is no default constructor for your Person class.  Java will automatically create a default constructor for any class for which there is no other constructor defined.  Since you defined a constructor, java will not automatically create one for you.  If you need a default constructor for your class, just define one.

Answer (score 3):

```
Person p1 = new Person();
```

This line fails because you have defined a constructor with parameters (and no constructor without parameters). If you don't define any constructor for your class, the compiler inserts an empty default constructor. But if you define any constructor at all, the compiler doesn't insert a default constructor, and it's up to you to provide the constructors you need.

Read these articles from the [Sun Java Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/):

- [Providing Constructors for Your Classes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)
- [Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)

Answer (score 2):

Your `Person` constructor requires two parameters. You have to pass two arguments when you call it in your test program.

Or you could create a second constructor that takes no arguments in your `Person` class.

Comment: isee. ive already tried new Person(name,age); but it says "cannot find symbol name" also for age.

Comment: You must give it actual values when you call it. Like `new Person("JGE18", 42);`. If you do `new Person(name,age)`, `name` and `age` must be variables that are visible in that scope.

Comment: isee, but the values are supposed to be given using command line arguements. Ill try new Person(name[],age[]); see if it works.

Comment: In your main test program, you do not define `name` as a variable anywhere. So you can't use that. Putting [] after something that does not exist (you haven't declared it in your main) will not solve anything. Please go through the first tutorial link Sean posted, you're missing quite a few Java basics.

Comment: ok, i will read and understand it. thanks. I have another question though. For example public void setOrigin(int x ,int y), is it really a different type of method? or the set part in its name is just for easier understanding? i mean is it the same with public void origin(int x , int y);

Answer (score 1):

You declared the Person constructor to require two args. Pass it two args.

Answer (score 1):

the constructor is

```
public Person(String name, int age)
```

so you cannot call

```
Person p1 = new Person();
```

but

```
Person p1 = new Person(name, age);
```

Of course, you need to define *name* and *age* first, which your program never seems to do...

Comment: i did declared the. Private String name and Private int age. and ive tried peron(name,age); already. but it says cannot find name and age.